# Toolbox doesn't work on visual studio for Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-2019

I am a beginner at c# and trying to install visual studio for coding on MacBook pro 2019-MacBigsur(the first time I am using Mac). When I tried to create a simple form like add/edit/delete. But on my Mac, visual studio doesn't have Toolbox for drag&drop elements. Then I tried to run this form for checking, I got an error: "mono64 quit unexpected".

Comment: Maybe you can report a problem on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=41).

Comment: I did a lot of report to them, but seem no hope and now I have to work, what should I do if I cannot run my project?